# Cannot get price using getSymbol in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to get historical price using the `quantmod` package but failed to do it. My code is just simply:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('MSFT', from = '2004-01-02', to = '2014-03-31')
```

Rstudio returns me this message:

> Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=",
>   from.m,  :  cannot open URL
>   'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?
>   s=MSFT&a=0&b=02&c=2004&d=2&e=31&f=2014&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=MSFT&x=.csv' In
>   addition: Warning message: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=",
>   Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : cannot open URL
>   'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?
>   s=MSFT&a=0&b=02&c=2004&d=2&e=31&f=2014&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=MSFT&x=.csv':
>   HTTP status  was '504 Maximum Transaction Time Exceeded'

However, if I specify the source, it works well:

```
getSymbols("MSFT",src = "google")
```

It seems there is a problem with Yahoo. I googled around but couldn't find any solution so far. Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: Maybe [it's broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055605/finding-the-second-highest-value-in-quantmod-by-time-period/44055956#comment75213275_44055956)?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the "'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com" URL in your browser you will see:

*Will be right back...
Thank you for your patience.
Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.*

Seems to be a temporary service issue.

Answer (score 1):

When your try directly the [address](https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=0&b=02&c=2004&d=2&e=31&f=2014&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=MSFT&x=.csv), your have the following message:

> Will be right back...
>
> Thank you for your patience.
>
> Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the patch. You can download with devtools:

```
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod", ref="157_yahoo_502")
```

Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/157#issuecomment-302159301) and comments that covers the yahoo error.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.